# How to access the Wikipedia in its entirety as an epub file?

Tags: kindle, epub, calibre, conversion, publishing

The built-in access to Wikipedia on the Kindle is lacklustre at best.  Even if it were out of date, might "the" Wikipedia be [available](https://www.vice.com/en/article/dyzxgm/you-can-download-the-entirely-of-english-wikipedia-to-browse-offline-using-kiwix) as an `epub` for download?  Or, perhaps that's such an extraordinarily large file as to defeat the purpose.  I would consider even side-loading such a file if it were available.

Individually, it's easy enough to download or convert individual articles for reference, of course.  Easy being relative, and, at least with my haphazard approach, a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked it up and it's not nearly as large as I thought. What's more they provide assistance in downloading it, although not as an Ebook.

[Wikipedia:Database_download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)

Google says:

> As of September 2022, the size of the current version of all English
> Wikipedia articles ***compressed*** ***without media*** is about **21.23 GB**.

**Just found this:**

[Wiki as E-Book Store](https://wiki-as-ebook.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: awesome, thanks for the good info.  Leaving open for a bit, but this looks to be the answer.

Comment: the link is dead now.